# Connection to remote server via file client

Tags: server, putty, winscp, ssh-tunnel

I have little problem. I am using Putty for connection to remote server.

```
ssh xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

After connection and login with password, I need to use command:

```
ssh username@servername
```

After this, I can use remove server via Putty, its work fine.

Now, I am looking for solution how to connect filemanager (WinSCP). I can connect to xxx.xx.xxx.xxx and browse filesystem here, but I cannot use secont ssh command for connection to computing server filesystem. How to solve this? Can I somehow open filemanager in Putty session location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, that the connection tunneling feature from WinSCP is what you are looking for: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tunneling